# How can i validate from jquery form submit ?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

i couldn't enable validation message on view ,because i use jquery to submit form.

Could any one have some idea to use validation with jquery submit form ?

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Sample", FormMethod.Post, new{ id="frmStep1"}))
 {
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Question 1:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
     <small class="text-danger">
         <i> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.answer_01)</i>
     </small>
     <div class="radio">
         <label>
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.answer_01,"2355")Male
         </label>
     </div>
     <div class="radio">
         <label>
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.answer_01,"2355")Male
         </label>
     </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btnStep1">
     <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right">
     </span> Save
  </button>
}
```

**Script**

```
$("#btnStep1").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "../Profile/Question",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $("form#frmStep1").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Ok');

            },
            fail: function(data) {
                console.log('failed to submit.');
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel model)
{
    return Json("success",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

i don't have any idea to enable validator on ViewModel to active when user couldn't input some text, pls give some idea to solve these solution.

Comment: Model validations work after javascriptvalidations. If you want your model validations to work then you have to take input type as submit OR you have to validate your each field in Javascript before submit

Answer (score 0):

You can Specify your action name and controller name in Form and take input type as 'submit', as given below:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("YourActionName", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new{ id="frmStep1"}))

   {
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>Question 1:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <small class="text-danger">
         <i> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.answer_01)</i>
      </small>
      <div class="radio">
       <label>
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.answer_01,"2355")Male
        </label>
       </div>
      <div class="radio">
       <label>
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.answer_01,"2355")Male
       </label>
      </div>
    </div>
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" id="btnStep1" />

}
```